# Debian Linux reload changes to interfaces file without a network restart

Tags: debian, linux-networking

I am new to Linux server administration and I am try out some network commands. 
I wish to change the network settings by modifying the /etc/network/interfaces file and want the changes to take effect immediately as possible. But I do not wish to restart the networking service, as it will cause disaster. We also want to avoid rebooting the system as much possible.
How to do it? I have used the ip commands and the ifup/ifdown commands, but for some strange reason, they sometimes fail. Where is any documentation or books to study this? 
Sorry for English.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `ifup/ifdown` is that it reads the current config to bring the interface up and down. So if you had, e.g.:

```
iface eno1 inet static
    address 1.1.1.1
    netmask 24
```

and you `ifup eno1`, what really happens is some `ip addr` and `ip route` commands executed. Among them you'll have `ip addr add 1.1.1.1/24 dev eno1`. If now you modify the file:

```
iface eno1 inet static
    address 2.2.2.2
    netmask 24
```

and you `ifdown eno1`, it will not execute `ip addr del 1.1.1.1/24 dev eno1` but `ip addr del 2.2.2.2/24 dev eno1`, hence the errors when you modify the config while an interface is up.

To work around this, backup the old configuration file before modifying it:

```
cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bak
```

and after you modified the configuration, use the backup for the `ifdown` command:

```
ifdown -i /etc/network/interfaces.bak <your_interface>; ifup <your_interface>
```

If you are connecting to the machine remotely, a good idea would be to reverse the operation after a timeout:

```
(sleep 180; ifdown <your_interface>; ifup -i /etc/network/interfaces.bak <your_interface>)&
```

If you lose connectivity, it should be restored after 180 seconds, otherwise you can just kill the job.

Comment: Thank much. But a doubt: how to otherwise you can just kill the job. Will the ssh session be disconnected by this?

Comment: Try a simple `(sleep 180)&`, bash will print the processes pid and you can kill it with `kill process_pid` (or `kill %job_number`). If you change IP the ssh session will break, otherwise it should continue.